# Parse data from external json file

Tags: php, json

I want to parse data from external json and its still giving me back error like

> Undefined offset: 6756 in /home/...

That wouldnt be so bad but it skip some rows, like 6756. Its in the json file but not in parsed text on my site.

You can find the site on this url http://skins4free.com/csgolounge.php

Here is code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $json = file_get_contents('http://csgolounge.com/api/matches_stats');
    $json_2 = file_get_contents('http://csgolounge.com/api/matches');
    $obj_2 = json_decode($json_2, true);
    $obj = json_decode($json, true);
    $matches = array();
    $matches_data = array();

    foreach($obj as $key) {
            array_push($matches, $key['match']); 
    }

    foreach($obj_2 as $key) {
            array_push($matches_data, $key['match']); 
    }

    $yet = max($matches);
    $blau = $yet - 100;

    echo '<span style="color:red">' . $yet . '</span><br>';

    if($obj){
        for ($i = $blau; $i <= $yet; $i++) { 
        echo $obj[$i]['match'] . ' - ' . $obj[$i]['a'] . ':' . $obj[$i]['b'];
        echo ' Date:' . $obj_2[$i]['when'] . ' Teams: ' . $obj_2[$i]['a'] . ' vs ' . $obj_2[$i]['b'] . '<br>'; 
        }
    }


?>
```

What is bad with my code ? I will be glad for every answer.
Thanks !

Comment: One of your `$obj`/`$obj_2` does not have an item at 6756. Add some defensive checks with `isset` to make sure `$i` actually corresponds to an entry in the arrays. If not, log it.

Comment: Thanks for advice. The problem was with offsets which doesnt equal to match IDs. But otherwise thanks :)